# Curl will not write errors out to a file

Tags: curl

I am looking to build an application that will tell the user if the port/address is open. I am unable to write failures to the file though.

I have tried using Curl to do this.

```
curl google.com:8099 --fail --show-error >”C:\Users\Ryan Lambert\Desktop\Curl.txt” && echo Success. || echo Fail.
```

Need to have errors come through in the file but file is empty. Running this in command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `stderror`, not `stdout`

For example:

`curl sosdlfjsdlfkj 2> log.something.error`

This would write the errors to the error log.

Comment: Changed from .txt to .error and nothing showed still. Empty file.

Comment: It has nothing to do with ".error", it's the `2>` instead of `>`